# VBA can't convert date stored in general

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now, I even managed to make it work by accident for a while, but a I had no luck since.

So I have a excelsheet with a column that has dates stored in this format: "yyyy.mm.dd hh:mm" (for example: 2021.01.02 11:40)
These dates are stored in a general cell formats, and I would like to store them in a Date variable so I can use the DateDiff function to determin how many days have passed between now and the stored date.
I can store them as String but whenever I try to convert it to Date I get the "Run time error '13': type mismatch" error.

I have a rather long and complicated code, so I wont share the whole thing. I'm still not sure how is this any help but here it is in it's current state with braX's solution:

```
    Dim Date1 As String
    Dim Date2 As Date
    Dim dayD As Long

    ...

    Date1 = ws.Cells(RowLoop, 124).Value
    MsgBox Date1
    Date2 = CDate(Replace(Date1, ".", "/"))
    MsgBox Date2
    dayD = DateDiff("D", Date2, Now)
    MsgBox dayD
```

ws refers to the worksheet it's from RowLoop is the loop this code is in

Comment: Sounds like your "dates" are not dates at all... but text. An Excel date is actually a number and what you are referring to as cell formats is really Number Formatting. VBA can absolutely convert any format to another, but you are not giving VBA what you think you are. Either convert the text "dates" in the worksheet to true Excel dates (numbers formatted as dates) or replace the periods in your text "dates" with forward slashes `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are stored as strings and not actual dates, you need to convert the periods to slashes first in order to convert them to actual dates:

```
Debug.Print CDate(Replace("2021.01.02 11:40", ".", "/"))
```

Not sure of your context, as you provided no code in your question.

```
Dim dt as Date
dt = CDate(Replace("2021.01.02 11:40", ".", "/"))

MsgBox "The date is: " & Format$(dt,"mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: That kinda worked. While I got the end result I wanted, it didn't actually do the replacement. 
So when I store it in a String and I put it in a message box it looks like: "2020.01.02. 11:40" and when I use the replacement you suggested i get this result: "2020. 01. 02. 11:40:00", so it just added spaces after the dots and put seconds at the end of the time. I might be wrong but I suspect the seconds might be the reason it actually works

Comment: Again, without you posting any code, it's hard to really know exactly what you are doing. Once it's an actual date tho, you can use `Format` to re-format it any way you want to. I added a bit to the answer for you.

Comment: Edited it with some code, but I doubt it's any use.

Comment: OK, so are you saying that the code you added worked for you then?

Comment: Well I got the end result I needed which is to get the diffrence in days between now and the date stored in the cell in question. It's just that things didn't work exactly as I expected them, but it serves its purpose.
Thank you for the help!